# Read NFC and write payload as keyboard input

Tags: android, nfc

I have a large group of people that owns NFC cards and i need to rewrite a program that uses these cards. Currently a raspberry pi is used to read these cards but i'd like to eleminate the need of this raspberry pi.

I want to buy a NFC reader compatible with android (lots can be found) but i'd like the nfc reader to read the payload of the card and send it to the android device as if it were keyboard input so i can just use a simple web application to use the cards.

Security is not a topic here.

What is the best way to achieve this on android (in the best case it also works on windows for development reasons).

Comment: Simulating text input can get pretty difficult an Android (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45021569/150978). I would keep the external hardware and try to simulate the input on hardware level using USB (as USB keyboard or via `adb shell input text ..` or simulated Bluetooth keyboard.